# Keep index of First dataframe when doing inner merge on columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes

```
ClientFileDf:

            Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN     CPCode       CPPAN   ClientPAN
0  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R        NaN         NaN         NaN
1  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR02  AACCG5797M  AACPB3698K
2  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AADCP2756J        NaN         NaN         NaN
3  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR04  AACCG5797S  AACPB3698K
4  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR06  AACCG5797M         NaN
```

and

```
df_CPCodeDF:

  HEDGE_CP_CODE HEDGE_PAN_NO
0     NCDXAGR02   AACCG5797M
1     NCDXAGR04   AACCG5797S
```

when I do Inner merge with columns I get resultant dataframe as below having index **0 and 1**

```
            Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN     CPCode       CPPAN   ClientPAN
0  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR02  AACCG5797M  AACPB3698K
1  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR04  AACCG5797S  AACPB3698K
```

While I need is  index as **1 and 3** respectively same as first dataframe

```
Required Df:

        Date Clearing Member PAN Trading Member PAN     CPCode       CPPAN   ClientPAN
1  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR02  AACCG5797M  AACPB3698K
3  1/10/2021          AAACS0581R         AAACS0581R  NCDXAGR04  AACCG5797S  AACPB3698K
```

I know index is ignored when doing merge with columns but is there a workaround or something I am missing ?

**MY Code:**

```
df2 = pd.merge(ClientFileDf, df_CPCodeDF,  how='inner', left_on=['CPCode','CPPAN'], right_on = ['HEDGE_CP_CODE','HEDGE_PAN_NO'])
df2.drop(['HEDGE_CP_CODE','HEDGE_PAN_NO'],axis=1, inplace=True)
print(df2)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `reset_index()` to keep the index of `ClientFileDf` and then set that index:

```
df2 = pd.merge(ClientFileDf.reset_index(), df_CPCodeDF,  how='inner', \
left_on=['CPCode','CPPAN'], \
right_on = ['HEDGE_CP_CODE','HEDGE_PAN_NO']).set_index('index')
```